# Windows Eyes and NVDA reading updated dom content with jquery....possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-readers

I have a web application that does most of my updates client side.

This application needs to meet some accessibility standards that I can't seem to get working.

Specifically, if I do something like this with a button click:

```
$("#myDiv").html("this is text that is now added to the page");
```

My screen readers are not reading that text unless I put my mouse over them.  Is there a way to force them to read any updated content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria), the Accessible Rich Internet Applications Suite to make you web application more accessible. you could add **Aria-live attribute** to specify the way to announce the refresh content:

- (off) Default. Updates should not be announced.
- (polite) Updates should only be announced if the user is idle.
- (assertive) Updates should be announced to the user as soon as possible.
- (rude) Updates should be announced immediately, interrupting the user if necessary.